# c++ fast method to select element in list

Tags: c++, performance, methods, probability

I have a list of elements composed by two elements: a number, and a string. I want to:
i) for each element of the list, generate a probability starting from the number combined with a given input (runtime)
ii) randomly select a string from the list according to the corresponding probability.

which is the fastest method to do it?

example: 
input: [[2.0, 'a'],[1.0, 'b'],[2.5, 'c']], runtime

(i): [[0.3, 'a'],[0.2, 'b'],[0.5, 'c']]

(ii): select 'c'

Comment: What techniques did you try and what problems did you have?

Comment: Could not understand "generate a probability starting from the number combined with a given input (runtime)"

Comment: 1. calculate sum of numbers, normalize probability 2. take random number [0..1], iterate through list until random number is larger than sum of previous entries and smaller than sum+current prob, take this list element 3. for faster search, implement skip list

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your list is potentially very large, so you want it to scale, rather than this tiny 3 element example has to be fast. My suggestion will probably slow your algorithm down for small arrays.

Convert your list into one where the number is the sum of your old number plus the previous sum. This makes it possible to do a binary search, since the numbers are in ascending order.

```
[[2.0, 'a'],[3.0, 'b'],[5.5, 'c']]
```

Then when you generate a random number, generate one between 0 and the last sum (0-5.5).

Then look at the middle element. If the number is less than your generated one, then look at the middle between that point and the end, etc. but if it's greater, then look in the middle between that point and the start, etc. until you have found the first number that is larger than your generated number, which is the selected element. (if you generate 0.5 in the above, then that means you select "a", or if you generated 2.1, then you select "b")

A binary search is efficient because the cost is only one more seek+read per doubling the set of options (32 reads in the array would find precisely the right answer in over 4 billion elements. 2^32 = 4294967296)